# Colormapping pie plots of pandas series

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, indexing, pie-chart, colormap

I have a double donut chart and I know how to colormap if I plot a DF, but that doesn't work with a series. How to put:

```
colors=outside['group1'].map(colors_outside),
colors=middle['group2'].map(colors_middle),
```

within the `plt.pie()` part? This is the example code:

```
df1   = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'], 
                  'group2': ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
              'count': np.random.randint(1,5, 6)})

# making the colormap
colors_outside = {'bar': '#FF1493', 'baz': '#FFFF00'}
colors_middle= {'one': '#FF3F33', 'two': '#8175E1','three':'#0A0096', 'four':'#960028'}
outside = df1.groupby('group1')['group1'].count()
middle =  df1.groupby(['group1','group2']).count()

# making the donut
plt.pie(outside, startangle=90, labels=outside.index)   # here I need: colors=outside['group1'].map(colors_outside),
plt.pie(middle, radius=0.75, labels=labels, startangle=90,  labeldistance=0.75 ) # here I need: colors=middle['group2'].map(colors_middle),
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5,color='black', fc='white')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the colors as follows:

```
outside_colors = [colors_outside[c] for c in outside.index]
middle_colors = [colors_middle[c] for c in middle.index.get_level_values('group2')]
```

Then use them inside the plot:

```
plt.pie(outside, startangle=90, labels=outside.index, colors=outside_colors)
plt.pie(middle, radius=0.75, labels=labels, startangle=90, colors=middle_colors, labeldistance=0.75)
```